# How to disable the "Confirmation" dialog when generating reports using script in PowerDesigner

Tags: powerdesigner

I have a script to generate report which is invoked from the command line: `"C:\Program Files\SAP\PowerDesigner 16\PdShell16.exe" -X pd-gen-reports.vbs`

The `report.GenerateHtml` function shows a dialog with prompt "Do you want to open it with the default application now" after successfully generating the HTML report and I have to manually click the "No" button.

Is there a way to disable this dialog so the script can be executed in automated build process without human interactions?

Comment: The appearance of the dialog, should be controlled by the `InteractiveMode` global property. Try setting it to im_Batch, to be sure, before calling GenerateHtml. If it does not work, it is a bug, should be reported, and you'll only have workarounds...

Comment: The `im_Batch` does not help for PowerDesigner 16.5.4.1, I reported in SAP community forum http://scn.sap.com/thread/3941882